# Arranging numbers is ascending order

Tags: java

I'm having troubles of arranging numbers starting from ascending form.

```
public static int median(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (( b < a && a < c) || (b > a && a > c)){
            return a;
        }
        if ((a < b && b < c) || (a > b && b > c)){
            return b;
        }
        return c;
    }
```

Basically when I run my code, it's supposed to find the median of the three numbers, however when I run the test code, it doesn't automatically arrange itself in ascending order. For Example, if the test code has the numbers (3,6,5), it will return the median as 6, however it should be 5.

Comment: The above code looks correct and it is giving the correct output for the input (3, 6,5)

Comment: When I run your code, with your sample arguments, method `median` returns 5. In other words, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get the median (based on your code) your variables a, b & c should be already sorted. You can sort your variables inside median function like

```java
public static int median(int a, int b, int c) {
        int max = Math.max(a , Math.max(b,c));
        int min = Math.min(a , Math.min(b,c));
        return a + b + c - max - min;;
}
```